# How to parse this kind of long string efficiently in Python?

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have a long string like this:

```
[left-ctrl]bhbhbhblbhbhblbhblblbhbl[left-ctrl][left-ctrl]blbhblbhblbbjbjbjblblbhblbhbhblbk[left-ctrl][left-ctrl]bhblblbjbjbkbjbkbjbkbkbh[left-ctrl]kkkkkk[left-cmd][tab][left-cmd][del]su[del][del]cut [del][left-shift];[left-shift][del]s[left-shift];
```

The actual string is much longer (160,000+ char). I want to treat `[...]` as a single char like `b`, `h`, ... . How?

---

**Edited:**

The problem is that a single `[` and `]` can appear like `[[[[[`, `]]]]]]`. My current idea is to use some library to pre-find the occurrence point of control chars like `[left-ctrl]`, `[cmd]`, ... . Then use a `cursor` to loop-through it and take special care when the cursor is at these special point. But this idea might take multiple round to pre-find these special points. I'm thinking about whether there is a simpler way to do so efficiently. Regarding using library I'm just too lazy to implement the KMP algorithm myself.

Notice that it's possible a single `]` without `[` will appear. E.g. `[left-ctrl]]hbh[left-ctrl]`.

Comment: This is not related to gaming. @KJ

Comment: I've edited my problem.  And, I don't think your behaviour fits the guideline too. I think it is worth asking before "guessing" people's intent. Are you saying that every question on this site needs to pair some codes with it? @KJ

Comment: I don't know why you're trying to change my problem. The keystrokes are recorded by a CLI tool that I cannot change the outcome. To change it like you said I still have to parse the string first. Do you really know what you're talking about? @KJ

Comment: This escaping convention for special key codes is ambiguous for some key sequences. For example, it will be impossible to distinguish `[` `d` `e` `l` `]` as a sequence of individual characters vs `[del]` as a single control character.  Perhaps you could get the source to escape brackets so they are never used as single characters (e.g. `[open-bracket]` and `[close-bracket]`, or double them up `[[` and `]]`). This would make parsing a lot simpler and reliable.

Comment: I'll delete my answer because I misunderstood part of the question, as @AlainT. has pointed out, and I don't want to replicate their answer, which is very good.

Comment: @DanielSchilling I think you misunderstood Rainnings request: I took it as a request for some explanations, which is justified.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1: Manual parsing**

You could define an iterator function that accumulates the bracketed characters and yields the special keys as keywords when the matching brackets are found:

```
def keyCodes(iKeys,maxLength=30):
    special = ""
    for c in iKeys:
        if len(special) >= maxLength:       # maximum code length
           yield from special               # flush characters
           special = ""                     
        if c == "[":                        # start of special char
            if special: yield from special  # flush prev. individual chars
            special = c                     
        elif c == "]" and special:          # closing bracket
            special += c 
            if len(special)>2: yield special       # special code
            else:              yield from special  # empty [], not a code
            special = ""                           # reset
        elif special:
            special += c                           # accumulate special code
        else:
            yield c                                # return simple chars
    yield from special                             # flush trailing chars
```

Output:

```
keys = "[left-ctrl]bhbhbhblbhbhblbhblblbhbl[left-ctrl][left-ctrl]blbhblbhblbbjbjbjblblbhblbhbhblbk[left-ctrl][left-ctrl]bhblblbjbjbkbjbkbjbkbkbh[left-ctrl]kkkkkk[left-cmd][tab][left-cmd][del]su[del][del]cut [del][left-shift];[left-shift][del]s[left-shift];"
for code in keyCodes(keys):
    print(code)

[left-ctrl]
b
h
b
h
b
h
b
l
b
h
b
h
b
l
b
h
b
l
b
l
b
h
b
l
[left-ctrl]
[left-ctrl]
b
l
b
h
b
l
b
h
b
l
b
b
j
b
j
b
j
b
l
b
l
b
h
b
l
b
h
b
h
b
l
b
k
[left-ctrl]
[left-ctrl]
b
h
b
l
b
l
b
j
b
j
b
k
b
j
b
k
b
j
b
k
b
k
b
h
[left-ctrl]
k
k
k
k
k
k
[left-cmd]
[tab]
[left-cmd]
[del]
s
u
[del]
[del]
c
u
t
 
[del]
[left-shift]
;
[left-shift]
[del]
s
[left-shift]
;
```

The function sets a maximum length for the `special` variable and flushes it when it reaches that maximum. This avoids storing a huge value in `special` waiting for a closing bracket that may never come.

A side benefit of this approach is that it can take an iterator as its input (as opposed to a regular expression which needs the whole string upfront).

*Note that, the condition (`if len(special)>2`) to determine if a special code should be output as a string or as individual characters probably needs to check against a list of valid special key codes (e.g. `if special in specialCodes`)  otherwise some key patterns may be returned as special codes when they are not (e.g. `[xxx]` or `[@]`).*

**Option 2: General regular expression pattern**

If you don't mind using a library, the same result can be obtained using a regular expression:

```
for code in re.findall(r'\[[^\]\[]{1,30}\]|.',keys):
    print(code)
```

The expression has 2 parts, searched in order of precedence (using the pipe (`|`) operator):

- `\[[^\]\[]{1,30}\]` : At least one character between brackets (excluding other brackets, maximum 30)
- `.` : any single character

*Like the previous solution, this may return invalid special codes for key sequences such as `[abc]`*

**Option 3: Specific regular expression pattern**

If you do have a list of the valid special codes, you can build a regular expression to extract them specifically:

```
specialCodes = ['[tab]', '[left-ctrl]', '[left-shift]', 
                '[del]', '[left-cmd]']
keyCodes = re.compile("|".join(re.escape(c) for c in specialCodes)+"|.")

for code in keyCodes.findall(keys):
    print(code)
```

The pattern is built using the pipe (`|`) operator to find the  special codes first and ends with a catch all single character (`.`) for normal keystrokes.

Regular expressions are known to sometimes be slow so I would suggest comparing the performance of these options on your data if processing is time sensitive (in my cursory benchmarking the regular expressions were more than 2x faster than the manual parsing with option2 being slightly faster than option3).

Comment: +1 for option 3. If we don't know the possible `[special-code]` values, then the worst case scenario would be if we encountered `[` near the beginning of a string, but then there was never a matching closing `]`. Listing all the possible `[special-code]` values gives the regex the best chance of stopping its search for a closing bracket as soon as possible. A similar alternative improvement, if all the possible special codes are not known, but we know their max length, would be to use `{n,m}` instead of `+` to limit the special code search length.

Comment: @Daniel Schilling, `{n,m}` is a very good idea for option 2 (and also for option 1).  I adjusted my answer accordingly, thanks.